# Windows Server 2012 Outbound HTTP Request Limit?

Tags: c#, http, tcp, ip, windows-server

Is there a limit to the number of outbound HTTP requests that can be made simultaneously on Windows Server 2012 Standard?

We're running a C# console app making HTTP calls (with many threads async) and noticing an increase in request times as more threads are added.

Comment: Have you configured [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, it is set to:

  <system.net>
   <connectionManagement>
  <clear/>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="10000" />
   </connectionManagement>
 </system.net>