# WCF Request time is increased when requests are inceased

Tags: multithreading, wcf, iis, parallel-processing

I have a service (WCF service hosted is IIS) as you can see here :

```
[ServiceContract]

    public interface  IInquiryService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Inquiry/{VisitDatetime}/{Plaque}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

        Inquiryview Inquiry(string VisitDatetime, string Plaque);
}
```

With this Implement:

```
 public class InquiryService : IInquiryService
    {
        private DataContext _ctx;
        private INajaService _najaService;
        private IUserService _userService;
        public InquiryService(DataContext ctx, INajaService najaService, IUserService userService)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
            _najaService = najaService;
            _userService = userService;
        }

        public  Inquiryview Inquiry(string VisitDatetime, string Plaque)
        {

            !!.....service
        }
}
```

Here is the service webconfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!--<added for security  />-->
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!--<added for security  />-->
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Inquiry.Service.AuthorizationManager, Inquiry.Service" />
         <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="1000" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Inquiry.Application.ServiceImplement.InquiryService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Inquiry.Domain.Service.IInquiryService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
      </service>
      <service name="Inquiry.Application.ServiceImplement.NajaInquiryService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Inquiry.Domain.Service.INajaInquiryService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <!--<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />-->
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST,PUT,DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    *****
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

So i call this service with two methods:

1- With 10 applications that each application has a one thread(foreach()):all response time for 2000 requests is about 200 ms.
2- With one application with multi thread ( Parallel.ForEach):The response time is 100 ms but when the requests are increased the response time is increased too ,i mean in the middle part of requests the response time reaches to 5000 ms ,in the end of requests the time reaches to 200 ms again .

So i think in some part the requests , queue is created but i don't know where ?

My client :

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Content = "Please Wait...";
            btnStart.IsEnabled = false;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                InquiryService service = new InquiryService();
                var items = Data.GetData(39000,40000).AsEnumerable();

                Parallel.ForEach(items , item =>
                {                    
                    string plaque = Plaque.GeneratePlaque(item.palll); //GeneratePlaque()//iran + "-" + ltree + lchar + ltow;
                    var result = service.Inquiry(plaque);
                    string serializedResult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);

                    FinalData finalData = new FinalData()
                    {
                        date = result.StartDate,
                        enddate = result.EndDate,
                        log = serializedResult,
                        plaque = plaque
                    };

                    FinalList.Add(finalData);

                    plaque = null;
                });

                //Data.InsertData(serializedResult, plaque, result);
                Data.InsertData(FinalList);

                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    btnStart.Content = "Start";
                    btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

The function that create requests :

```
public Result Inquiry(string Plaque)
        {
            string result_ = "";
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) => { return true; };
            DateTime start;
            DateTime end;
            using (WebClient ClientRequest = new WebClient())
            {
                ClientRequest.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
                ClientRequest.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                NetworkCredential credential1 = new NetworkCredential("1", "1");
                ClientRequest.Credentials = credential1;
                start = DateTime.Now;
                result_ = ClientRequest.DownloadString(ServiceHostName + "/Inquiry/2012-12-28" + "/" + Plaque);
                end = DateTime.Now;

            }
            var javascriptserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Result temp = javascriptserializer.Deserialize<Result>(result_);
            temp.StartDate = start;
            temp.EndDate = end;

            return temp;
        }
```

I change some IIS config as you can see :

[image]
[image]

The times for 2000 request with multi thread:

763
762
844
919
165
558
527
574
518
209
238
227
252
221
304
198
283
296
291
266
271
197
195
238
241
297
238
315
201
247
305
319
309
322
341
213
304
236
339
228
234
384
429
383
409
345
387
360
287
327
388
413
455
434
442
410
423
368
368
271
290
285
281
284
284
297
320
302
309
311
325
333
156
310
348
326
531
308
304
293
327
310
309
306
307
287
305
302
358
318
399
318
304
426
314
299
323
643
350
631
385
613
313
397
469
276
298
290
264
288
572
353
296
439
317
426
359
519
334
478
331
496
313
513
358
321
433
324
439
405
381
386
361
363
342
363
386
225
307
421
329
501
502
403
410
417
404
458
443
437
624
435
373
635
359
563
670
468
378
371
500
419
539
463
563
457
590
559
575
516
576
545
541
535
480
589
446
636
511
454
631
470
641
640
483
426
642
423
627
416
598
404
602
446
413
631
400
585
401
556
393
553
419
409
421
388
904
379
381
888
365
380
939
951
482
971
628
647
599
689
716
628
646
748
629
647
591
539
497
603
488
441
582
545
439
454
547
558
491
454
571
512
530
560
564
574
583
603
603
467
590
437
733
424
664
378
630
404
502
511
947
544
944
624
619
897
605
911
649
1009
671
683
641
700
625
633
632
616
576
619
504
450
382
681
551
563
462
443
556
459
479
479
491
535
487
603
508
533
631
575
690
577
691
670
575
533
672
616
517
589
471
441
550
551
544
545
544
712
742
625
732
636
736
751
641
641
816
638
574
558
674
539
612
459
572
607
704
663
645
641
649
639
640
655
682
538
733
625
613
905
634
713
629
711
697
783
650
736
696
700
701
733
712
713
724
727
664
664
689
668
664
664
616
648
621
619
630
628
615
626
622
638
605
488
493
705
589
673
575
495
555
806
553
789
555
721
557
723
558
543
719
689
532
528
726
683
543
513
690
526
527
466
782
701
518
704
725
512
621
723
732
660
670
753
699
714
725
749
763
816
755
703
836
608
817
800
582
787
551
524
987
541
559
626
625
631
651
656
1378
653
1594
673
1429
702
711
1352
730
1394
1474
763
773
1506
759
1499
809
897
853
820
935
777
911
775
1004
759
984
759
781
999
957
773
947
778
931
803
818
910
924
837
790
877
818
893
778
874
790
790
879
868
797
830
760
859
765
815
832
836
782
838
756
758
849
841
760
863
759
800
749
929
768
939
723
946
755
961
959
779
744
944
749
960
925
738
934
770
867
871
855
853
871
1225
954
1261
955
1258
990
1247
1276
1025
1287
1075
1290
1277
1081
1125
1079
1076
915
1063
950
992
963
1121
1233
1269
1154
1141
1230
1150
1188
1224
1287
1253
1356
1263
1385
1220
1398
1198
1390
1015
1375
1163
1037
1030
1142
1012
1116
975
1108
978
1090
947
1048
1085
1005
1081
1014
1136
1055
935
1183
940
1124
928
1219
1217
897
1225
943
1250
1035
1217
969
1124
1008
1041
1181
1110
1016
1119
1154
1180
1190
1187
1232
1229
1230
1200
1183
1070
1556
1020
1068
1548
1017
1000
1655
977
1731
1021
1758
1017
1028
1725
1027
1825
1734
1068
1713
1074
1022
1648
1050
1354
1044
1414
1097
1113
1483
1124
1091
1456
1124
1511
1088
1484
1453
1117
1186
1186
1484
1499
1194
1178
1134
1422
1387
1125
1080
1390
1380
1112
1084
1412
1427
1074
1046
1398
1061
1413
1014
1019
1429
1307
1079
1078
1368
1040
1001
1372
1379
1179
1410
1265
1421
1293
1427
1407
1352
1440
1364
1406
1440
1440
1453
1468
1498
1483
1532
1513
1585
1580
1541
1509
1550
1506
1525
1581
1567
1603
1585
1567
1606
1554
1591
1513
1465
1586
1521
1432
1517
1482
1462
1508
1536
1565
1536
1539
1557
1595
1518
1572
1464
1562
1437
1541
1448
1461
1535
1491
1559
1444
1431
1594
1661
1347
1590
1385
1645
1376
1644
1625
1529
1418
1432
1518
1445
1431
1532
1568
1560
1556
1591
1523
1714
1547
1709
1520
1725
1508
1745
1474
1481
1717
1498
1708
1528
1608
1661
1689
1640
1358
1653
1716
1680
1604
1624
2048
1590
1796
1601
1596
1855
1877
1622
1586
1909
1549
1979
1603
1980
1928
1570
1570
1986
1592
2025
1569
1507
1996
1781
1975
1491
1684
1547
1570
1925
1481
1888
1852
1558
1834
1582
1635
1859
1648
1612
1702
1696
1566
1631
1574
1627
1770
1630
1781
1652
1806
1768
1685
1788
1753
1722
1752
1736
1814
1697
1721
1831
1607
1778
1659
1775
1717
1862
1723
1899
1570
2002
1598
1959
1585
1706
2036
2180
1957
2152
2047
1956
2000
1997
1967
1958
2009
1941
1913
1888
1874
1890
1838
1887
1737
1827
1777
1856
1640
1410
1403
1422
1449
1395
1522
1422
1467
1298
1309
1344
1316
1617
1592
1570
1628
1602
1603
1570
1554
1461
1481
1474
1426
1242
1209
1305
1306
751
1016
766
877
908
753
712
874
591
889
587
889
625
836
615
611
510
607
494
453
477
762
453
644
536
558
743
630
577
469
617
563
490
442
566
532
409
371
396
275
384
265
385
294
391
258
423
286
261
355
361
278
354
244
335
234
224
224
198
235
182
163
214
374
175

Comment: what OS is hosting your services (client and server)

Comment: My service is hosted in windows server 2012 and my client is windows server 2012 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has ha limit of outbound http traffic, have a look at that config, and tune if for your needs.

[Windows Server 2012 Outbound HTTP Request Limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577431/windows-server-2012-outbound-http-request-limit)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/add-element-for-connectionmanagement-network-settings

Comment: Thank you but as I said when I call the service with 10 applications with 1 thread it works